# remove certain files except others

Tags: command-line, delete

I found so many suggestions as to how to remove files with exceptions. However, this case is a little different.
Let's say, I have 6 files as follows in my **Ubuntu 18.04**:

```
text_1.json
text_2.json
video_1.mp4
video_2.mp4
video_1_notouch.mp4
video_2_notouch.mp4
```

The command should remove only `video_1.mp4` and `video_2.mp4` files while leaving other files as is.

I tried `rm -v !(*.json|*_notouch.mp4)` as suggested [here](https://www.tecmint.com/delete-all-files-in-directory-except-one-few-file-extensions/), but it removed all 6 files.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include 0. Your Ubuntu version , 1. What is your problem 2. Now what do you want after removing those files 

Comment: What do you mean by removed everything ?

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: oops, it's 18.04, not 16.04, sorry for a typo

Comment: what does `shopt extglob` say?

Comment: @bac0n It was when I used the command, now it's off

Comment: I think shopt extglob is set by bash-completion, but you may also append it to `~/.bashrc`, it's not inherited though, so you will have to re-set it when you intend to invoke a new shell, e.g., `bash -c 'shopt extglob'` may be written *bash -O extglob -c 'shopt extglob'*

Comment: `rm` is permanent and not undo-able. If you have risk because files-to-keep and files-to-delete are mixed together, then implement basic risk management controls: Separate the steps (use `find`) or separate the files into tempdirs. Or take the time to go file-by-file. Read your output carefully and test your findings before deleting. It will save you many tears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better and easier to use the `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" ! -name "*_notouch.mp4" -exec rm -v {} \;
```

This command will match any file name ending with `.mp4`, but not with `_notouch.mp4` and will run the command given after `-exec`.

Before such destructive operations, it always wise to prepend or replace the `rm` command with an `echo` and verify you are getting the commands you are expecting:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp4" ! -name "*_notouch.mp4" -exec echo rm -v {} \;
```

**[Edit]** As mentioned in the comments; in your case, you can just use `-print -delete` in place of `-exec echo rm -v {} \;` (which will be more efficient if you have millions of files). And to list the files that will be affected (before running the destructive command) you can just run:

`find . -type f -name "*.mp4" ! -name "*_notouch.mp4"` (`-print` is optional)

Also, if you *do not* want to affect subdirectories, you can use the `-maxdepth 1` option like this:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.mp4" ! -name "*_notouch.mp4"`.

Comment: better use `+` instead of ```\;```

Comment: or `find -type f -name '...' ... -print -delete`